# Service broker error: {"description"=>"Not permitted on a disabled service instance: 10301"}

Tags: ibm-cloud

I attached a SQL DB service to a bluemix app. Later I created a new app. I then unbound the SQL DB service from first app. 
When I Try to bind the service to the new app I get error -

Service broker error: {"description"=>"Not permitted on a disabled service instance: 10301"}

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

A service instance would normally be disabled if there was a billing issue i.e. you have a charge on the service but your credit card was declined. If you was using the Free Beta plan for SQLDB then it shouldn't be a billing issue.

The only thing you can do is to send the information about your service instance (id etc) to [Bluemix Support](https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/) to look at your particular service instance to find out what the problem is.